# How get all value in same row without using multiple joins conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I have below table structures

### Student

```
Stud_ID | First_Name | Last_name | Contact
ID001   | AAA        | AAA       |     111
ID002   | BBB        | BBB       |     222
```

---

### StudUser

```
Stud_ID | NUM | Value
ID001   |  10 | English
ID001   |  20 | Math
ID001   |  30 | Science
ID002   |  10 | English
ID002   |  20 | Math
```

---

Expected Output

```
Stud_id | First_name | 10      | 20    | 30
ID001   | AAA        | English | Math  | Science
ID002   | BBB        | English | Math  |
```

**Current query I'm using**

```
select 
        stud_id,
        First_name,
        EG.EGUV AS "10",
        LE.LEUV AS "20",
        FPS.FPSUV AS "30"
from 
        student,
        (SELECT STUD_ID AS EGS,USER_VALUE AS EGUV FROM STUD_USER WHERE COL_NUM='10') AS EG,
        (SELECT STUD_ID AS BUS,USER_VALUE AS BUUV FROM STUD_USER WHERE COL_NUM='20') AS BU,
        (SELECT STUD_ID AS AUS,USER_VALUE AS AUV FROM STUD_USER WHERE COL_NUM='30') AS A
where
        ST.STUD_ID=EG.EGS(+) and 
        ST.STUD_ID=BU.BUS(+) and    
        ST.STUD_ID=A.AUS(+)
```

**Please let me know if there is any other optimized way to get all user Values.**
**Note : this table structure cannot be altered only read permission is available**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Oracle **[PIVOT](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html)** clause for this.
It will (*sort of*) dynamically create additional columns according to values of a selected column.

This is the query I used (using **WITH** clauses to simulate your input data):

```
WITH
Student
AS
    (SELECT 'ID001' AS Stud_ID, 'AAA' AS First_Name, 'AAA' AS Last_name, 111 AS Contact FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ID002', 'BBB', 'BBB', 222 FROM DUAL),
StudUser
AS
    (SELECT 'ID001' AS Stud_ID, 10 AS NUM, 'English' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ID001', 20, 'Math' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ID001', 30, 'Science' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ID002', 10, 'English' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ID002', 20, 'Math' FROM DUAL),
Prepare
AS
    (SELECT ST.STUD_ID,
            ST.FIRST_NAME,
            SU.NUM,
            SU.VALUE
       FROM STUDENT ST LEFT JOIN STUDUSER SU ON ST.STUD_ID = SU.STUD_ID)
SELECT *
FROM Prepare PIVOT (MIN (VALUE) FOR NUM IN (10, 20, 30))
```

The **PIVOT** function expects an aggregate function, because it will go over all of the results where e.g. `STUD_ID = ID001 and NUM = 10` and will return a value according to the aggregate function that was used. Your example implies the combination of `STUD_ID and NUM` will be unique for the **StudUser** table, therefore most of the Oracle's aggregate functions will do, as they will have to go over just one value. If the combination wasn't unique, you would have to take a second to think about a way you would like to aggregate them.

The **FOR** section of the **pivot** clause lets you specify which values you would like to turn into columns. This, unfortunately cannot be generated dynamically, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM Prepare PIVOT (MIN (VALUE) FOR NUM IN ( SELECT DISTINCT NUM FROM StudUser ))
```

That would be invalid and wouldn't compile.

You can also specify desired **column names** for the pivoted columns, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM Prepare PIVOT (MIN (VALUE) FOR NUM IN (10 Subject1, 20 Subject2, 30 Subject3))
```

I found the **PIVOT** clause merely by searching: **oracle turn values into columns**, so I kinda guess you didn't find it because you weren't sure how to call this. Can't blame you.